# output only the first 10 properties of For in loop in Javascript

Tags: javascript, for-in-loop

I got a problem to do the next thing. 
I am learning javascript from scratch and can't get next exercise to work perfectly.

The question is to display with a for-in loop the first 10 properties of the object navigator. 
I got the next code that displays all properties but can't find out to only show the first 10. 
(It has to go with a for-in loop does the exercise say.

```
for (var i in navigator) {
        document.getElementById('divResult').innerHTML +=
            i + ': ' + navigator[i] + '<br />';
    }
```

can anyone help me out?

Kind Regards!

Comment: `navigator` add it to ur answer

Comment: If `navigator` happens to be an array (you just said `object`), then note that `for-in` is not guaranteed to produce the indices in order. (Your use of `i` as a property name is a bit suggestive of an index.)

Answer (score 1):

One very simplistic way to do it is just use another variable to count for you, and `break` out of the loop when it reaches 10:

```
var count = 0;
for (var i in navigator) {
    document.getElementById('divResult').innerHTML +=
        i + ': ' + navigator[i] + '<br />';

    count++;

    if (count > 9) {
        break;
    }
}
```